# Testing interface through scapy

Tags: networking, architecture, scapy, packets

I try to develop a software that need to received packets (kind of a webserver)
For that I  have a card with 2 interface connected between them (xgbe1 and xgbe2) and connected to a pc through a 3rd interface (tilep2p1)

My software listen to both xgbe1 and xgbe2, i have assign them ip : 10.1.0.3 and 10.1.0.4 and netmask 255.255.255.0

3rd interface have ip 10.1.0.2 and the pc connected have on its interface 10.1.0.1 (both netmask 255.255.255.0)

I try to test my software through scapy that work on the PC but not on the card, but i have no clue how to know if the packet i send through scapy goes to the right interface and so it is my software that have a problem or if i use scapy wrong.

Here is my scapy code :

```
    a = IP()/TCP()
    a.dst = 10.1.0.3
    a.src = 10.1.0.1
    a.port = 80
    a.send
```

Ps : My software can not listen to tilep2p1.

I can not directly connect xgbe1 to a machine because i do not have access physically to the room where those machine are.

The question is : How to know that the packet is indeed received by xgbe1 ?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: What happen when you send a SYN segment (`a = IP(src=10.1.0.3)/TCP(flags="S")`) or an ICMP echo request (`a = IP(src=10.1.0.3)/ICMP()`) to 10.1.0.3? Do you see a SYN-ACK segment/an ICMP echo reply with wireshark or tcpdump on the pc?

Comment: You can use `pkt = sr1(a)` instead of a.send to record the response to your packet.  Then `pkt.summary()` to show you the summary of the response.